# Swiftdata three level relationship not working in SwiftUI preview

Tags: relationship, swift-data

There is a 3 level relationship in my model:

Parent(One) -> Child(Many) -> GrandChild(Many)

The way it is set up is working fine in the simulator, but the preview crashes when adding code to manipulate the GrandChild. Am I doing something wrong?

The App:

```
@main
struct Test_ModelApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(for: [Parent.self, Child.self, GrandChild.self])
    }
}
```

The model:

```
@Model
final class Parent {
    
    var name: String
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Child.parent)
    var children: [Child]
    
    init() {
        self.name = "Parent"
    }
}

@Model
final class Child {
    
    var name: String
    
    var parent: Parent?
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \GrandChild.child)
    var grandChildren: [GrandChild]
    
    init(parent: Parent) {
        self.name = "Child"
        self.parent = parent
    }
}

@Model
final class GrandChild {
    
    var name: String
    
    var child: Child?
    
    init(child: Child) {
        self.name = "Grandchild"
        self.child = child
    }
}
```

A simple test View:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var parents: [Parent]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Button("Add parent and children") {
                let parent = Parent()
                
                modelContext.insert(parent)
                
                let child1 = Child(parent: parent)
                let child2 = Child(parent: parent)
                
                modelContext.insert(child1)
                modelContext.insert(child2)
                
//                for child in parent.children {
//                    
//                    let grandChild1 = GrandChild(child: child)
//                    let grandChild2 = GrandChild(child: child)
//                    
//                    modelContext.insert(grandChild1)
//                    modelContext.insert(grandChild2)
//                }
                
            }
            
            ForEach(parents) { parent in
                HStack {
                    Text(parent.name)
                    Button("Remove") {
                        modelContext.delete(parent)
                        
                        do {
                            try modelContext.save()
                        } catch {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    }
                }
                ForEach(parent.children) { child in
                    Text(child.name)
                    ForEach(child.grandChildren) { grandChild in
                        Text(grandChild.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    
    ContentView()
        .modelContainer(for: [Parent.self, Child.self, GrandChild.self], inMemory: true)
}
```

This works fine in the preview until I uncomment the code related to adding the grandchildren. In the simulator it works as expected.

Comment: This works fine for me both when running the app and in the preview. What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Thanks for checking this out for me Joakim. I am using Xcode 15 Beta 6.

Comment: Same for me, maybe try cleaning the build folder and deleting derived data

Comment: Thanks, that didn't work sadly. Currently completely reinstalling Xcode, see if that helps. :)

Comment: Reinstalling Xcode and related files didn't work. Completely reinstalled MacOs, still nothing. Are you sure you uncommented the code in ContentView when using the preview?

Comment: Yes I did and reinstalling software or the OS should never be needed for something like this. What does the preview crash log say?

Comment: My target is macOS and not iOS but it shouldn't affect the preview or SwiftData behaviour

Comment: Couldn't add the crashlog here, pasted it here https://pastebin.com/HGBSk9h8

Comment: I had 3 separate files, 1 for each model. As soon as I moved all the model classes to one file it started working. No clue why this is happening.